DHTMLX Spreadsheet export to xlsx as blob
I have DHTMLX Spreadsheet v5.x in my Angular project.
I need to push the updated Spreadsheet file to the server.
The built in method creates and autodownloads the xlsx file.
let spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet(spreadsheetContainer.nativeElement, {
    menu: true,
});
spreadsheet.export.xlsx();

Is it possible to intercept the file created inside external library, So that i can create a blob and push to the server side?
Is there any other way to extract spreadsheet as xlsx?

You can check the json2excel library using for the data export to excel in the dhx.Spreadsheet:
https://github.com/DHTMLX/json2excel/tree/master
it allows to get the converted data as a blob file.
